# How I can display data from database in my html without refresh the page each time I clicked on input?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Each time I click on the input, I send data to database and I display it in html but I need refresh the
page for display how to do without refresh each time ?

Do I have to add one function name refresh page with `setInterval`? I don't know if it's good to do that

**HTML**

```html
<section>
  <h2>Les membres d'équipages</h2>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]">
      <td>{{mydata.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</section>
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  getUrl: string = 'http://localhost/get.php';
  postUrl: string = 'http://localhost/post.php';

  array = [];

  reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(),
  });

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMethod();
  }

  postMethod() {
    let myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);

    return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData,
      { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
        (response) => console.log(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  getMethod() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.getUrl).subscribe(data => {
      this.array.push(data);
    }, error => console.error(error));
  };

  onSubmit() {
    this.postMethod();
  };
}
```

Comment: You could use a websocket.

Answer (score 1):

In your POST method you are only printing the response you need to assign that response to your `array` i.e

```
postMethod() {
  let myFormData = new FormData();
  myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);

  return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData,
   { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
     (response) => this.array.push(response),
     (error) => console.log(error)
   );
}
```

Or you can simple call your GET method after success response of POST i.e

```
postMethod() {
  let myFormData = new FormData();
  myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);

  return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData,
   { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
     () => this.getMethod(),
     (error) => console.log(error)
   );
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: thanks for your help i try this :                                     
                                                                                    
    postMethod() {
    let myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);

    return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData,
      { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.array.push(response);
        },
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
is that correct ?

Comment: @Richard I have updated my answer now you can try both example.

Comment: I tried the two examples it still doesn't work I have to refresh the whole page

Comment: Both of these techniques should work. But note that your HTML contains this: `*ngFor="let mydata of array[0]"`, which causes it to only display the first item in the array. It looks like you need to change it to this: `*ngFor="let mydata of array"`to display all of the elements of the array.

Comment: if i remove this *ngFor="let mydata of array[0]" there is nothing more displayed with the [0] I have all my data in the table that is displayed